# Suppressing word wrap in TextBox and RichTextBox (yes, it is turned off)

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have tried both the regular TextBox and RichTextBox in an app where I don't want any word wrap. Yes, of course I turned off word wrap in Properties. This is something that occurs at extremely long lines, like around 3000 chars or so in the RichTextBox (regular TextBox much sooner, but I can get by without it if RichTextBox works). I recognize that it is cruel and unusual punishment to subject the poor RichTextBox to such line lengths, but unavoidable. Still, it seems like abnormal behavior.

The text is just long continuous strings of repetitive ascii (genetic data), so nothing unusual there. In fact it's usually just A,C,T,G with no punctuation or spaces.

Is this known behavior?

Comment: It is cruel and unusual punishment to the *user*.  Don't create utterly useless UI like this, nobody will actually ever look at it.  It is normal behavior for RTB, it doesn't support infinity.  Actual width depends on the font.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a RichTextBox and extend the right margin to the width of the text.

richTextBox1.RightMargin = TextRenderer.MeasureText(yourString, this.richTextBox1.Font).Width;

This way you maintain the ability to have other lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WinForms, both `RichTextBox` and `TextBox` have built-in limits for lengths of lines.

An alternative is to use a scroll viewer and manually add `Label`s. I do not believe there will be any limit in this scenario, although I could be wrong.

If you check Notepad (notepad.exe) in Windows, it also has a limit before it starts wrapping text, so this is standard behavior for Windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

the `Multiline` property should be false in order for the lines not to wrap.